# How should I structure these gradle task dependencies?

Tags: gradle, flyway

I have these gradle tasks:
- `startTestDatabaseContainer`: builds and starts a docker container with a database
- `removeTestDatabaseContainer`: stops and removes the docker container
- `flywayValidate`: a task from [`org.flywaydb.flyway`](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/gradle/validate) that validates my migration files

I wish to run these three tasks in order. Reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21612729/understanding-gradle-task-dependency-dependson) leads me to this solution:

```
flywayValidate.dependsOn startTestDatabaseContainer
flywayValidate.finalizedBy removeTestDatabaseContainer
```

This works ok, but then I can't run `gradle flywayValidate` from the commandline without `startTestDatabaseContainer` and `removeTestDatabaseContainer` also being invoked. I want to be able to run  `flywayValidate` without that happening.

What can I do to accomplish this when I cannot have ordered dependencies in gradle?

My first attempt was simply:

```
task validateMigration {
    dependsOn startTestDatabaseContainer
    dependsOn flywayValidate
    finalizedBy removeTestDatabaseContainer
}
```

But that fails because `flywayValidate` can run before `startTestDatabaseContainer`.

Edit: I've setup a demonstration base on [Opal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/542270/opal)'s solution here: [github.com/stianlagstad/flyway-migration-error-causes-final-gradle-task-to-not-execute](https://github.com/stianlagstad/flyway-migration-error-causes-final-gradle-task-to-not-execute). Clone it and run `gradle validateMigration`. The migration will fail and the final gradle task won't run (and `docker ps` will show the container still running). If you fix the migration file then everything works as expected. I'm sure I'm misunderstanding something. Any pointers would be helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
task validateMigration {
    dependsOn startTestDatabaseContainer
    dependsOn flywayMigrate
    flywayMigrate.finalizedBy removeTestDatabaseContainer
    flywayMigrate.mustRunAfter startTestDatabaseContainer
}
```

This did the trick! Thank you [orzeh for the PR on Github](https://github.com/stianlagstad/flyway-migration-error-causes-final-gradle-task-to-not-execute/pull/1/files), and thank you [Opal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/542270/opal) for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The following setup should meet all your requirements:

```
task startTestDatabaseContainer {
  doLast {
    println 'startTestDatabaseContainer'
  }
}
task flywayValidate {
  doLast {
    println 'flywayValidate'
  }
}
task removeTestDatabaseContainer {
  doLast {
    println 'removeTestDatabaseContainer'
  }
}

task validateMigration {
    dependsOn startTestDatabaseContainer
    dependsOn flywayValidate
    flywayValidate.mustRunAfter startTestDatabaseContainer
    finalizedBy removeTestDatabaseContainer
}
```

**EDIT**

```
task removeTestDatabaseContainer {
  doLast {
    println 'removeTestDatabaseContainer'
  }
}

task startTestDatabaseContainer {
  doLast {
    println 'startTestDatabaseContainer'
  }
  finalizedBy removeTestDatabaseContainer
}

task flywayValidate { t->
  doLast {
    println 'flywayValidate'
    throw new TaskExecutionException(t, new RuntimeException('whatever'))
  }
}

task validateMigration {
    dependsOn startTestDatabaseContainer
    dependsOn flywayValidate
    flywayValidate.mustRunAfter startTestDatabaseContainer
}
```

[Here](https://github.com/Opalo/stackoverflow/tree/master/46280142)'s a demo.

Comment: Thank you! I ran into another problem with this: When the migration fails the `removeTestDatabaseContainer` task isn't ran (I confirmed this by adding a doLast with a println + seeing that the docker container is still running). If I remove the two lines about `flywayValidate` inside the `validateMigration` task, then `removeTestDatabaseContainer` is ran successfully. Do you have any tips?

Comment: Thank you again. However, it doesn't seem like the `removeTestDatabaseContainer` is called. I'll edit my original question to show you what the output looks like for the code in your edit.

Comment: Sorry, looks like I ran the wrong command. Will test a bit further.

Comment: Your example works well :) It just doesn't work in my project. I'll create a reproducible example.

Comment: I've setup a demonstration here: https://github.com/stianlagstad/flyway-migration-error-causes-final-gradle-task-to-not-execute. Clone it and run `gradle validateMigration`. The migration will fail and the final gradle task won't run (and `docker ps` will show the container still running). If you fix the migration file then everything works as expected. I'm sure I'm misunderstanding something. Any pointers would be helpful :)

Comment: I've figured out that this works as I want: `gradle startTestDatabaseContainer flywayMigrate removeTestDatabaseContainer --continue`. I have to add `--continue` there to make `removeTestDatabaseContainer` run even when `flywayMigrate` fails. Now my challenge is to write a single docker task for this.

Comment: Ah.. Sure. `--continue` is an option, however it should work without it as well.

Comment: If you have the chance to test the example I provided I hope you'll get the same results as me: The `removeTestDatabaseContainer` won't run because `flywayMigrate` fails.

Comment: @L42, prepared a PR on GH - check it out. It should work right now.