# Default actions in custom plugins

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

I am working in a Gradle custom plugin using gradle-api and need to setuo an action that is executed always, like a configuration task.

I have created some tasks this way:

```
class MyTask extends DefaultTask {
    @TaskAction
    void myAction() throws Exception {
        [my action code]
    }
}
```

and then adding to the project as:

```
class MyPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    @Override
    void apply(Project project) {
        project.getTasks().create("myTask", MyTask.class)
    }
}
```

... and these works: when I explicitly call for the myTask goal it is executed, but I need a task that is executed every time even when not explicitly called.

Comment: So why don't you put the logic inside the `apply` method?

Comment: *always* is a strong word. I doubt anyone would want that code to run if the command is just, for example `gradle tasks`. You probably want to create a config task that another existing task (yours or base gradle tasks like assemble or build or check) depend on, so that whenever that existing task is run, your config task is also run. If you explained what concrete stuff you're trying to achieve, it would be easier to help.

Comment: you can check https://discuss.gradle.org/t/add-task-to-end-of-all-other-tasks/7183/6 which describe one possible solution, that I think would fit in your case

Comment: @Opal that does not solves the problem.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks indeed for trying to help me, I really appreciate this community, but please dont blame on me if you dont know the answer. I am fine with "always".

Comment: @M.Ricciuti thanks, that was helpful, but finally I found my own way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have found the way:

The idea is to configure my action as a configuration.
I guess there are several ways but this one I like:

```
class MyPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    @Override
    void apply(Project project) {

        final MyTask myTask = project.getTasks().create(
                "myTask", MyTask.class
        )

        project.getConfigurations().create(
                "myTask",
                {
                    myTask.myMethod()
                }
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute code every time when grable is running, you can add your code to `apply` method directly or inside block `afterEvaluate`:

```
class MyPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
  @Override
  void apply(Project project) {
    project.getTasks().create("myTask", MyTask.class)
    // your code...
    // or
    project.afterEvaluate(proj -> {
      // your code...
    });
  }
}
```

If you need to put you code specifically in `task` then you should make your task `dependsOn` an existing task (the task is already registered in the DAG - directed acyclic graph). For example:

```
MyTask task = Tproject.getTasks().create("myTask", MyTask.class);
project.getTasks().findByName("assembleDebug").dependsOn(task);
```

About `dependsOn` you can see in [docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:adding_dependencies_to_tasks) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21613441/9060113).

**Deprecated:**

Also, in the old version of the Gradle, you can do `yourTask.execute()`, but now it is deprecated.