# Generated code stays in build folder after Android Studio Build

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, generated-code, gradle-task

I am using a `gradle` task to generate some code for my API and store this code into the `build` folder. When I am building my application the process deletes the build folder.

Is there a way to call my code generation task between the folder deletion and the start of the compilation?

Comment: Are you using a custom gradle task? Please show how you generate the code for your API. In gradle you can make your custom tasks depend on other tasks. You could hook in your custom code generation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21612729/understanding-gradle-task-dependency-dependson

Comment: I know how how to call other tasks , but my problem is to call my task on time after the build folder have been deleted and put my generated code in there , so the compile will find the classes that i need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After allot of trying , i found the solution .
In the `build.gradle` i had to add the `preBuild.finalizedBy(generateCode)`

Answer (score 0):

**I am not a Gradle expert, so their might be better answers!**

In your `build.gradle` you can create custom tasks and make them depend on other tasks:

```
// this is your new task
task generateCode() {
  description 'Generates some code...'
  doLast {
    println("generateCode")
    // do your code generation here
  }
}

// put the name of the task you wanna depend on, like: compileSources
project.task("compileSources").dependsOn generateCode
```

When you call this task `./gradlew compileSources` you should see that the custom task `generateCode` gets executed first.