# Understanding Gradle dependsOn example code

Tags: gradle

I'm trying to understand the fundamental idea of what gradle calls a "dependency". Specifically, I am confused by the example code given in the [Task Dependencies Section](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html#sec:task_dependencies) of the Gradle user guide. It has been my understanding to this point that a "dependency" is something that is somehow imported to a given project (project in the general sense, not the gradle type) and can be used by something within your project, but not necessarily entirely used or evaluated. In the example they give, it appears the dependent task `'hello'` is also evaluated.

```
tasks.register('hello') {
    doLast {
        println 'Hello world!'
    }
}
tasks.register('intro') {
    dependsOn tasks.hello
    doLast {
        println "I'm Gradle"
    }
}
```

Output of gradle -q intro

```
> gradle -q intro
Hello world!
I'm Gradle
```

Is the idea of a "dependency" in gradle just completely different and only a way to specify the order of operations rather than importing some functionality from some other package? Is there any way to use/evaluate only part of some other task rather than the whole thing (making it more similar to my preconceived idea of a dependency).

What further confused me is the idea of dependencies discussed in the [Core Dependency Management](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/core_dependency_management.html) section of the User Guide. This seems to align better with my preconceived ideas of what a dependency is.

Unless I'm grossly misunderstanding all of this, in the same user guide it seems we have to separate ideas of what a "dependency" is:

1. some task that must be run prior to the task you are currently within.
2. an external package with functionality you want to import for your own use.

How does one know which the user guide is referring to when the word "dependency" is used?

I found a related post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21612729/understanding-gradle-task-dependency-dependson) but this just mentions this idea as a "small gripe" but isn't directly addressed by the answers.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting confused between two uses of the word 'dependency' in any build system (not just Gradle):

1. The dependency you've quoted in your opening post is a dependency between build targets (called 'tasks' in Gradle). This defines the order in which the tasks get executed. So, if you execute the 'intro' task (by running 'gradle intro'), the dependsOn definition says that 'intro' depends on 'hello', so 'hello' must be executed first, then 'intro'. The execution occurs because you ran a build with a target of 'intro'
2. The second kind of dependency is the one you're expecting, i.e. the dependency the build has on external libraries that will need to be imported for the build to work. These dependencies are defined in the 'dependencies' closure in a Gradle build script.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting confused about the meaning of the word "dependency".

A dependency only implies that 1 thing needs (depends on) another thing. It has nothing to do with importing packages.
If your code depends on other code then to be able to compile it, it needs to be imported. So because it's a dependency gradle will download the jars and put them on the classpath for you.

A task dependency is similar, you just say, to run this task, that task needs to run (or be up-to-date) first.

```
tasks.register("that")
tasks.register("this"){
 dependsOn("that")
}
```

Comment: My confusion still exists in that the contents of these dependencies gradle downloads as jars aren't all executed, while the contents of a task dependency are. They would be equal if all things in the jars were within the `main()` method, or just class defined variables, but not if the jars contained some class definitions that never get initialized or used. Is there a similar means of selectively running some, but not all things within a dependent task? Or some way to call only certain parts of a task? Can a task define a class or something that is not immediately initialized?

Comment: As your task `that` doesn't contain anything, there is no real confusion between the two ideas, but to reiterate using the code I posted, I'd expect `dependsOn tasks.hello` would allow the `intro` task to have access to whatever is within `hello`, but not execute its contents, when in fact it appears to actually execute its contents.

Comment: Another more practical example is in any standard android Gradle file, you list your dependencies in the dependencies block, but when building, as you said, gradle will download the jars and put them in the classpath, but it will not execute the entire contents of each jar and print every log message in the whole android api to your console.

Comment: Dependency does not (always) imply execution. I depend on my colleagues, but I don't execute them, i work with them. I depend on food, I dont execute it, but I eat it. I depend on sleep, that I kinda "execute" i guess.
What I'm trying to say "dependency" just states a relationship. What that relationship is about exactly it does not say. In gradle tasks it does imply execution of the dependent on task, in gradle code dependencies it implies importing.

Comment: Exactly! Why does a task dependency imply execution? You hit the nail on the head with you last sentence. This difference is precisely what I am confused about. Why do gradle tasks imply execution of a dependent task and gradle code imply importing? All of your examples fit my 2nd and preconceived idea of what a programming dependency is. You declare you depend on your colleagues, but it takes some other step (line of code) to do something with that (e.g. executing a conference call with them). Declaring you depend on sleep should not put you to sleep immediately.

Comment: So the answer to "How does one know which the user guide is referring to when the word "dependency" is used?" is if it is in a task declaration or not. Although I'm still rather unsatisfied, I think we're getting too off topic for SO. Why don't you just add the above conclusion, along with something along the lines of "for better or worse,  when declaring gradle task dependencies this implies execution, while declaring gradle code dependencies do not. A task is dependent on the successful execution of another task, while code is dependent only an api being imported and available for use."